# delete duplicates based on location with jdupes fdupes or similar

Tags: duplicates, delete-file

I'm trying to move from an old system to a new system, and carefully clean up the old drive. (*bsd and linux apply, working in both systems if flags differ)

My problem is deleting duplicates based on location. I want to keep everything on the new drive, and only delete from the old drive. Say, the new drive is /new and the old drive is /box-to-import. If I run fdupes or jdupes, even with --order=words and/or -i, I can't get the first option (default save, delete rest with -N flag) to be the preferred location.

I can change the directory names to a, b, c, or something as long as the sort by name includes the directory name, I can prioritize. But I can't get this option to work. What should I be trying?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request for this on the `jdupes` GitHub but I have not implemented it yet. For now your best bet is to use a custom script. [There is a script in the source tree that does something similar to what you're asking](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes/blob/master/example_scripts/delete_but_exclude_nonposix.sh) with the only exception being that the first item in a match set is always preserved, which guarantees that at least one file will always be preserved.

Of course, if you're only trying to delete duplicates on the old drive and aren't concerned about guaranteeing that you are preserving at least one copy then it's pretty easy to do a duplicate scan against both drives and delete all matches found on the old drive without even using a shell script:

`jdupes -r /old /new | grep '^/old' | while read -r X; do rm -f "$X"; done`

Note that if you do this and there are duplicates on the old drive that aren't present on the new drive at all, you'll delete all copies and thus lose data. To make sure a copy exists on `/new` before nuking all dupes on `/old` you need a much more complex script that consumes an entire match set, scans the set for at least one match in the "good" place, then **only after this confirmation** re-scans the match set and deletes everything in the "bad" place. I haven't written an example script for this; it would require storing each line in Bash/ksh/zsh arrays and running multiple loops to process the data.